# Dev tools Network Tab, open script in Sources tab?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

In Chrome Dev Tools, when viewing the Network tab, is it possible to select a script and open it in the Sources tab? Double-clicking the script opens it raw in a new browser tab.

Because the Sources tab organizes all assets by their source domains (along with folder paths), it can be time consuming to locate a particular script, if you don't know immediately where it came from. You have to switch back and forth between Network and Sources, taking note of the domain and folder path in the script's header and then trying to dig through all the source domain's and subfolders until you locate the script.

It seems like there should be some obvious way of opening a script in the Sources tab from the Network tab, but I don't see how. You appear to have to manually dig to find it.

Comment: It just landed in Chrome Canary - see https://twitter.com/umaar/status/552086893190713344 . Thanks for bringing this up!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT**

This feature is now available in Chrome Canary, and should be available in stable Chrome in a few weeks.

[image: Chrome DevTools - Network - Open in Sources Panel]

---

As far as I know this is not possible right now. I think it's a good idea though, so I reported it for [you](http://crbug.com/443088).

The quickest way, I can think of, to open a script from the network tab in the sources tab is to:

- copy/memorize name of the script from network tab,
- go to the sources tab,
- open file search (<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> / <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>),
- enter name of the file you are looking for.

Comment: Hey that `cmd+P` is really helpful. I had no idea that was even in the dev tools. That does help a lot. Thank you.